# Compute limit by induction ("inductive step of existence" issue)

Tags: calculus, limits, induction, limits-without-lhopital

I was asked to compute the limit 
$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k) - 2^n}{x-1}$

My approach was as follows

i) Define $L(n):=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k) - 2^n}{x-1}$

ii) $L(1)$ exists and trying to write $L(n+1)$ in terms of $L(n)$, it turns out that $L(n+1)$ exists iff and $L(n)$ exists (from second line of the following equalities)

$$\begin{align*} L(n+1) & = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (1+x^k) - 2^{n+1}}{x-1} \\ & = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left( 2\times \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k) - 2^n}{x-1} + \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\times \prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k)\right) \\ & = 2L(n) + (n+1)\times 2^n \end{align*}$$

iii) the algebraïc identity linking $L(n)$ and $L(n+1)$ is $L(n+1) = 2L(n) + (n+1)\times2^n$

iv) Then I defined $l(n):=\dfrac{L(n)}{2^n}$ noticing that it satisfies the telescopable relation $l(n+1)-l(n) = \dfrac{n+1}{2}$

v) Computing $l(n)$ then $L(n)$ now is easy and it yields $L(n) = 2^{n-1}\times \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

My question is that a friend objected step (ii) (third line in aligned equations) telling me that the problem of existence is not solved yet the way I did it, and that we can't do such a manipulation when expressions we manipulate are not justified beforehand to exist.  As I see it, since $L(1)$ exists and figuring out that $L(n+1)$ exists iff $L(n)$ does, is enough to this issue of existence.

I wonder whether I'm right or wrong and is the proof I provided rigorous enough, otherwise what do I need it to add to get it better

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your approach. You proved correctly that:

1. The limit $L(n)$ exists if and only if the limit $L(n+1)$ exists.
2. If both of them exist, then $L(n+1)=2L(n)+(n+1)2^n$.

So, now, since $L(1)$ exists, it's only a matter of using induction to compute the value of $L(n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear reply.
The point (1.) you mentioned and the existence of $L(1)$  are enough to state that $L(n)$ exists for all $n$, aren't they ?

Comment: Yes, they are sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

Your ideas are correct.In the second step i would suggest not to take limits because you do not know of the limit in the left hand side exists.Just do the computations of the  limits on the right hand side  of the equality which we know that exist from the induction hypothesis and etc.

> Then after you compute these then you take limits to the left hand side.
>
> using the fact that the limit of $f+gh$ at a point $x_0$ is equal to  $\lim f+(\lim g \lim h)$
>
> if $\lim g,\lim f, \lim h$ exist at $x_0$(and are real numbers).

Here it is another proof of the existence with the notion of derivative:

Also to make clear i use just the definition of derivative and not the L'Hospital rule because of the tag.

This limit exists $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ because:

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
>
> Take the function $f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x^k)$ which is differentiable.
>
> We have that $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x^k) -2^n}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)$$

Now if you want, you can use induction to compute $f'(1)$ as an exercise.

Comment: I'm sorry not to have mentioned that earlier, but it was asked to compute the limit without using the concept of differentiation

Comment: @OussamaSarih..i understand but in this limit i do not use L'Hospital..i just used the definition of derivative at $x_0=1$

Comment: That's very helpful in the sense that it clears the doubts regarding existence. 
Yet, my original question regarding my approach remains unanswered.

Comment: @OussamaSarih..ok i will examine the question again

Comment: @OussamaSarih ...see my edits if you want.

Comment: Your edits clarify many points. Thanks @Mario Gretsas for your valuable suggestions and advice

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: In fact, logarithmic differentiation would probably make it very easy to compute $f'(1)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler maybe..i just proposed to the O.P to find it with induction to practise this proof method

Answer (score 5):

You did right: the proof of existence of $L(n)$, for all $n\ge1$, is good because you know that $L(1)$ exists and that $L(n+1)$ exists as soon as $L(n)$ does.

A different strategy showing the power of differential calculus is to realize that this is the derivative at $1$ of
$$
f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x^k)
$$
and that, for $x>0$,
$$
\log f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+x^k)
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{f_n'(x)}{f_n(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{kx^{k-1}}{1+x^k}
$$
and, taking into account that $f_n(1)=2^n$, we get
$$
f_n'(1)=2^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2}=2^{n-2}n(n+1)
$$
No fancy telescoping and other troubles. I understand you have not yet done derivatives; when you'll have done them, check back and judge for yourself what's the best strategy.

Comment: Awesome. I actually studied derivatives but the original problem asks to compute the limit without making use of differentiation. 
I like the idea of using the logarithmic differentiation here to differentiate this product, it didn't even come to my mind ^^.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, by a combinatorial way, we have that

$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k) - 2^n =(1+x)(1+x^2)\ldots(1+x^n)-2^n =\overbrace{1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}}^{\text{$2^n$ terms}}-2^n=$$

$$=\overbrace{(x-1)+(x^2-1)+\ldots+(x^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}-1)}^{\text{$2^n-1$ terms}}=$$

$$=(x-1)\left(1+(x+1)+(x^2+x+1)+\ldots+(x^{\frac{n(n+1)}2-1}+\ldots+1)\right)=(x-1)\;S(x)$$

and since for $x\to 1$

$$S(x)=1+(x+1)+(x^2+x+1)+\ldots+(x^{\frac{n(n+1)}2-1}+\ldots+1) \to S(1)$$

where $S(1)$ is the sum of all elements of all subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ which is

$$S(1)= 2^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2^{n-2}n(n+1)$$

since each number occurs in $2^{n-1}$ subsets, therefore

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k) - 2^n}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)\;S(x)}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} S(x)=S(1)= 2^{n-2}n(n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $x\equiv 1+\varepsilon$ then
$$
\newcommand{\lime}{\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0 }\frac1\varepsilon}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1 }
\frac{ \prod_{k=1}^n (x^k+1)  - 2^n}{x-1}
=\lime\left({\prod_{k=1}^n ((1+\epsilon)^k+1)-2^n}\right)\\
=\lime((1+\varepsilon)+1)\left(((1+\varepsilon)^2+1)...((1+\varepsilon)^n+1)-2^n\right)\\
=\lime\left(
(2+\varepsilon)
(2+2\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2))...(2+n\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)))-2^n\right)\\
$$
$$=\lime\left(2^n+2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n i\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)-2^n\right).
$$